# How does Propel determine which database to use for command-line tools?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

How does Propel determine which database to use for *command-line tools* (ex. "propel:build-all")? I'm setting up two environments (production and staging), and the databases will be different for each.

Is it "propel.ini" or "databases.yml"? If the former, does symfony auto-generate that file?

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which environment to use in the Propel tasks (and many other tasks) by using the `env` argument:

```
./symfony propel:build-all-load --env=staging
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch database engine on command line:

This will generate the code for MySQL

```
symfony propel:build-all --phing-arg="Dpropel.database=mysql"
```

while this will generate the code for PostgreSQL

```
symfony propel:build-all --phing-arg="Dpropel.database=pgsql"
```

If you are using multiple databases you define main one in `propel.ini` and you define the other ones in `databases.yml`.

I'm not sure if you can generate `propel.ini` but you can download example one from [here](http://qubit-toolkit.org/wiki/index.php?title=Example_propel.ini_file)

Comment: Thanks for the tip RaYell. That's close to the conclusion I came to for myself, except you can actually load the database from the environment of your choice (see below). Thanks again!